# Excel getting value from sheet2 to my other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Here's the lowdown. I am needing to get a value from Sheet1 and calculate that with a number in order to get a percentage.

I know I can grab the default value from Sheet2 like this:

```
=Sheet2!AA2
```

The calculations on sheet one look like this:

```
=1-(AA2/Z2)
```

My question is how can I get the value from **Sheet2**, and at the same time, calculate that using the **=1-(AA2/Z2)**?

The *AA2* and also the *Z2* are both located on *Sheet2*.

As an example of what I am looking to do:

Lets say *=Sheet2!AA2*'s number is $822.00

Let's also say that *Z2*'s number is $1,549.00

So I would need it to do the following:

```
1549/822 = 1.9% (rounded)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=1-Sheet2!AA2/Sheet2!Z2`

Comment: I tried that but it just keeps putting *=1-Sheet2!AA2/Sheet2!Z2* **as text inside the box** instead of giving me that calculated value??

Comment: Look at the cell format - it may be set as Text and thus not calculating the formula.

Comment: Ah, that was it! Thanks for the help, Taosique!